# "Out of memory" error from Perl when processing files

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl with [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) to process a large batch of text files. I need to count the occurrences of all the words that end with certain suffixes.

Running this code keeps returning `out of memory` error messages for batches of over, say, 40 files.

Is there any way to accomplish this task more efficiently (less memory usage) than what I'm doing below?

```
#!/software/perl512/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $path = "/data/10K/2012";
chdir($path) or die "Cant chdir to $path $!";

# This program counts the total number of suffixes of a form in a given document.

my @sequence;
my %sequences;
my $file;
my $fh;
my @output;

# Reading in the data.
for my $file (<*.txt>) {

   my %affixes;
   my %word_count;

   my $data = do {
      open my $fh, '<', $file;
      local $/;    # Slurp mode
      <$fh>;
   };

   my $dom  = Mojo::DOM->new($data);
   my $text = $dom->all_text();

   for (split /\s+/, $text) {
      if ($_ =~ /[a-zA-Z]+(ness|ship|dom|ance|ence|age|cy|tion|hood|ism|ment|ure|tude|ery|ity|ial)\b/ ) {
         ++$affixes{"affix_count"};
      }
      ++$word_count{"word_count"};
   }

   my $output = join ",", $file, $affixes{"affix_count"}, $word_count{"word_count"};

   push @output, ($output);
}

@output = sort @output;

open(my $fh3, '>', '/home/usr16/rcazier/PerlCode/affix_count.txt');
foreach (@output) {
   print $fh3 "$_\n ";
}
close $fh3;
```

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: "Out of memory" is not a syntax error.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to have a `%word_count` hash with only a single key called `word_count`; just use a scalar (i.e. `$word_count`). Same applies to your `%affixes` hash.

Comment: Have you tried doing any memory usage profiling?

Comment: The title wasn't very descriptive, my bad. @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, you are correct, I'm getting an "out of memory" message, which is not an error message per se.  I see what you're saying about changing my two hashes to scalars.  After making that change, I'm still getting the process killed due to a lack of memory.  Any other ideas? As far as memory usage profiling, running the free -m command indicates 64,410 total memory, of which 3,398 is used and 61,011 is free.

Comment: I've altered your question quite substantially so that I can understand it better myself, and in the hope that it will help others to assist you. Please check that it is accurate. `Mojo::DOM` is for processing HTML files. Do your "text" files contain HTML? It is unusual for HTML files to have a `txt` file type.

Comment: @Borodin, your altered phrasing of my question is accurate. Most of these text files do contain HTML tags. I'm not terribly familiar with the Mojo::DOM, but it seems to correctly parse the text from the HTML tags.  If there is a more memory-efficient way to count the number of words ending in certain suffixes for each of several thousand documents, I'd love to learn what it is.

Comment: My comment about hashes vs. scalars would not affect memory usage, it was simply one of several examples of things in your code that don't make a lot of sense. Based on this and your previous questions, it seems like you're hacking things together piece by piece based on Stack Overflow answers, but may be lacking a fundamental understanding of each of the pieces and how they fit together. Have you worked through a good *modern* Perl tutorial?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Yes, I am continuously tweaking the same bit of code as I experiment with different ways to accomplish a series of related tasks. I'm pretty new to Perl, so it is piecemeal, but I've gone through the first 10 chapters of the Learning Perl (llama) book and am trying to put things together for a specific project.

Comment: That's great that you're using Learning Perl (as long as it's a relatively recent edition). I'd like to point out a number of things in your code that could be improved, many of which have nothing to do with your memory issue. Alas, there's not enough room in the comments, so the things that stand out most are: 1) As Borodin said, it doesn't make sense to use `Mojo::DOM` for regular text files. 2) Process files line by line instead of slurping them into memory. 3) To copy a file, use [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) instead of reading it into an array and then writing it.

Comment: Oops, ignore point 3 above, you're not actually copying a file. You are, however, slurping the text of each file into a scalar and then splitting the words into a list, roughly doubling your memory requirements.

Comment: Did I say doubling? You're actually storing the raw text in one scalar before stripping the HTML tags (if there are any), then in a `Mojo::DOM` object, then in another scalar after stripping the tags, and then in a list after splitting. That's a lot of copies of basically the same data. If your files are large, that could eat up a sizable chunk of memory. Be aware that even if your machine has plenty of free memory, the OS limits the amount allocated to each running *process*.

Comment: I was under the impression slurping the text allowed the Mojo::Dom to strip out the HTML tags correctly.  I can verify that the Mojo::Dom line works to remove HTML tags from my .txt files, which are filled with HTML tags. If there is a more efficient method for removing all HTML tags than using Mojo::DOM in this context, I'll take it.  I've seen that parsing HTML tags using regex is discouraged, so I've avoided that.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: You're probably right - the memory vanishes in `Mojo::DOM->new($data)`, and all to remove HTML tags that may not even exist. Since this code looks like it's trying to find parts of speech I don't think the stuff inside the tags will matter, and if it does then an `XML::Parser` solution that processes the text chunks one by one is the way to go.

Comment: @Rick: You are right: as far as I can tell `Mojo::DOM` requires an entire document to parse. But that is probably where your memory is going. I think you can probably safely ignore the tags embedded in the text, and if you can't then a fully-functioning HTML parser isn't the best choice.

Comment: It appears ThisSuitIsBlackNot and Borodin have identified the problem area in my code that is taking up so much memory.  I will make adjustments accordingly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as near as I can get to a solution. It incorporates all the points that have been made in the comments, and solves the *"Out of memory"* error by leaving any HTML tags intact. It also leaves the result unsorted as the original code doesn't really do any useful sorting.

Because of the way you are looking for suffixed words, I think it's very unlikely that leaving HTML tags in your text files will pervert your results significantly.

```
#!/software/perl512/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

# Build and compile a regex that will match any of the suffixes that interest
# us, for later use in testing each "word" in the input file
#
my $suffix_re = do {
   my @suffixes  = qw/ ness ship dom ance ence age cy tion hood ism ment ure tude ery ity ial /;
   my $alternation = join '|', @suffixes;
   qr/ (?: $alternation ) /xi;
};

# Set the directory that we want to examine. `autodie` will check the success
# of `chdir` for us
#
my $path = '/data/10K/2012';  
chdir $path;

# Process every file with a `txt` file type
#
for my $filename ( grep -f, glob('*.txt') ) {

   warn qq{Processing "$filename"\n};

   open my ($fh), '<', $filename;

   my ($suffixes, $word_count) = (0, 0);

   while (<$fh>) {
      for (split) {
         ++$word_count;
         ++$suffixes if /\A[a-z]+$suffix_re\z/i;
      }
   }

   say join ',', $filename, $suffixes, $word_count if $suffixes;
}
```

Comment: @Borodin-your code works like a charm!  I was able to use your code to run my data without exhausting my memory.  Thanks!

Comment: @Rick: You're very welcome, and I'm pleased that I was able to help. In future, please do you best to describe carefully the *problem* that your code is supposed to solve, as well as the code that isn't working for you. I had to work backwards from your Perl to a best guess about what the original problem may be, and then write some code that solved my guess. I realise that it can be difficult to specify a problem, but it is frustrating that, very often, we are presented with a *proposed* solution together with a program that doesn't work. The *original problem* is vital for us to help you.